# Post data with curl (php) and then get sessionid from GET

Tags: php, curl

So here is my problem:
I want to login to a website using curl, and I send the login credentials with POST. However, after the successful login, I get redirected to a url, where my sessionid is passed with GET (and not in the cookies, so no way to get them from there). I would need that sessionid to access to the protected pages. So, how do I get it?

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
```

and then follow with parse_url() and then parse_str()

Comment: this only shows me the url I sent the request to, and unfortunately, the sessionId is not set there, only after logging in.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's exactly what I did.

Comment: use print_r() to see all the values getinfo returns. Maybe its named differently.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sessionId = parse_url( curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL) )['sessionId'];
```

Change *'sessionId'* to the token name being used.